# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined - underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm just starting to learn underscore js, just want to see the result of this simple exercise, but the console.log is not working for me, below the code

```
    <script>

        var Array = [1,2,3,'hello',5]

         function StringArray(){
          for(var i = 0;i<Array.length;i++)
            if(typeof Array[i] ==='string')
           _.each(Array[i]);
         }

    </script>

 console.log(StringArray());
```

Comment: Do you realize you are overwriting the built in Array?

Comment: What is `_.each(Array[i]);` supposed to do, nothing? Did you actually want to do a `_.filter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the iterator function as the second argument to `_each`, i.e.:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,'hello',5]
```

function StringArray() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(typeof arr[i] ==='string') {
            _.each(arr[i], function(element, index, list) {
                console.log(element);
            });
        }
    }
}

StringArray();

I also changed your var name from `Array` to `arr` to avoid overwriting the built-in Array.